# What's the website for running SQL queries on Stack Overflows database?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I knew I've visited it but I just can't remember the URL.

The website consists of a number of user submitted SQL queries that return remaining points to badges, top users in a week and much much more.

I am truly sorry if this has been asked before but for the life of me I can't find the question.

Comment: FYI: The website in question allows you to query on the latest (currently monthly) [data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump), *not* on the live database.

Comment: Thanks @Jon I did realise that when I noticed my upvotes aren't even close to what my profile page says :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! Accepting in 8 minutes.

Comment: To add to this, there is now a "data" link in the site footer which takes you to SEDE.

Comment: @JonSeigel Doesn't seem to be one that I can see... but the link in the answer still works fine.